# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lenght')

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Quiero lllenar una tabla con registro de la base de datos, para eso utilizo ajax pero cuando levanto el programa, el data me dice que no tiene esa propiedad de length

```
var table, data;

function addRows(data) {
    table = $("#table_id").dataTable();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        table.fnAddData([
            data[i].id,
            data[i].name,
            data[i].description,
            data[i].price,
            data[i].idSector
            //'<button type="button" value="Actualizar" title="Actualizar" class="btn btn-primary"> </button>'
        ]);
    } }

function sendDataAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        URL: "Articulos.aspx/loadGrid",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            addRows(data.d);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.d)
        }
    }); }

sendDataAjax();
```

Comment: Escribiste mal `length`, intenta cambiando el nombre.

Comment: Hola, ahí lo cambié pero me sigue levantando ese error

Comment: 2 cosas, la primera es que el código debes ponerlo como texto y no como imagen. La segunda es que debes explicar cual es el comportamiento que esperas de tu código para que puedan ayudarte.

Comment: Quiero lllenar una tabla con registro de la base de datos, para eso utilizo ajax pero cuando levanto el programa, el data me dice que no tiene esa propiedad de length

Comment: ¿Que esperas obtener? Un Json? un Array?

Answer (score 0):

Revisa esta línea:

```
addRows(data.d);
```

A la función addRows le estás pasando como parámetro el valor `data.d`, y luego en esa función intentas acceder al valor `data.length`. Chequea que data.d tiene el campo length (o sea, si `data.d.length` es correcto o en cambio deberías pasar directamente `data` a la función para acceder a `data.length`)